# How to undefine in fsi?

Tags: f#, fsi

I re-defined `ref`, for example, by mistake. And it replaced the default `ref`.

Is it possible to remove my definition and restore to the original one without restart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let ref = Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.ref;;
```

Comment: Interesting, I tried `let ref x = { contents = x };;` too and `:=` works too. The type is different though. One is `val it : ('a -> 'a ref) = <fun:clo@48-2>` while another one is `val ref : x:'a -> Ref<'a>`.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 : Try `let ref x = Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.ref x;;` instead if you want to resolve that discrepancy.